# Javascript array of hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create an array with different hrefs to then attach to 5 separate elements.

This is my code:

```
var link = new Array('link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5');

                    $(document.createElement("li"))
                    .attr('class',options.numericId + (i+1))
                    .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"page.php# + 'link'\">'+ '</a>')
                    .appendTo($("."+ options.numericId))
```

As you can see I am trying to append these items from the array to the end of my page so each link will take the user to a different section of the page. But i have not been able to do this. Is there a way to to create elements with different links?

I am new to javascript so I am sorry if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If anyone is confused by what i am asking here I can try to clarify if I get some feedback.

The code I would Like output is:

```
    <ul class="controls">
    <li class="controls1"><a href="page.php#link1"></a></li>
    <li class="controls2"><a href="page.php#link2"></a></li>
    <li class="controls3"><a href="page.php#link3"></a></li>
    <li class="controls4"><a href="page.php#link4"></a></li>
    <li class="controls5"><a href="page.php#link5"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Which is similar to what I am getting, however when I apply the fix that andres descalzo has supplied, my list elements are each repeating themselves 5 times.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

jason

Comment: Why don't you put it directly into your html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?:

***Edit II *** for comment

```
var link = ['strategy', 'branding', 'marketing', 'media', 'management'],
          refNumericId = $("."+ numericId);

  $(link).each(function(i, el){

      $("<li></li>")
            .attr("id", numericId + "_" + (i+1))
            .attr("class", numericId + (i+1))
            .html("<a href=\"capabilities.php#"+el+"\"></a>")
            .appendTo(refNumericId);

  });
```

I saw your code in the file 'easySlider1.7.js' and you're including in 'for' of the line 123 the code 'var link = [' strategy,''which should go after this 'for'

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response. This method works great for appending the links. however, it is creating each of my list elements 5 times. Any ideas on how to fix this.

again thank you so much for the help.

Jason

Comment: you create a total of 25 links. you call five times the variable "link"?

Comment: Let me try and explain more clearly. I want to call the variable link only 1 time. Creating 5 different links. What this looks like is http://www.perksconsulting.com/dev/index.php. I am trying to append a different href to each of the 5 icons along the bottom. these hrefs are the 5 links.. link1, link2 etc. 

Using your method I can append the hrefs I want to the icons, but it creates each icon 5 times, when I only want them each once.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So when I try this I am still getting the icons appearing multiple times: http://www.perksconsulting.com/dev/index.php. 
I am familiar with the iterator function, is there something I should be changing to limit the amount of times it repeats the creation of these elements?

Thanks

Comment: I have edited my question to include what I want my output code to be.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean with the placement of 'for'. I'm sorry I am very new to javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, as there is some undefined values and syntax errors in your code, but here is an example on how to create elements from an array and add to an existing `ul` element:

```
$(function(){
    $.each(['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5'], function(i, link){
        $('<li/>')
        .append(
            $('<a/>')
            .attr({ 'class': 'c' + i, ref: i, href: 'page.php#' + link })
            .text(link)
        ).appendTo('ul');
    });
});
```

With the existing `ul` element, it produces:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="c0" ref="0" href="page.php#link1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="c1" ref="1" href="page.php#link2">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="c2" ref="2" href="page.php#link3">link3</a></li>
  <li><a class="c3" ref="3" href="page.php#link4">link4</a></li>
  <li><a class="c4" ref="4" href="page.php#link5">link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

(In place of the array literal `[...]` you could of course use an array variable.)